# assign variable to multiple argparse attributes

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

I'm trying to assign multiple argument attributes based on their location in the attribute list. To give an example;

```
import argparse
import sys

def args_options:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', help='-s argument help', nargs=3)
    parser.add_argument('-k', help='-k argument help', nargs=3)
    arguments = parser.parse_args()

    return arguments

def assign_arg():
    args = args_options()

    if args.s or args.k:
        variable1 = args[1] # this is where I'm stuck as I know this won't work
        variable2 = args[2] # ^
```

From the above, I'm trying to check if either arg.s or arg.k is true, and if so then the second and third attribute in the list of either argument is assigned to variables.

Is it possible to do this with python? Or would I need to do;

```
if arg.s:
    variable1 = arg.s[1] 
    variable2 = arg.s[2]
elif arg.k:
    variable1 = arg.k[1] 
    variable2 = arg.k[2]
```

The above would work, but I have a lot of options/attributes so the code could get long. Wanted to ask if there way to do it more efficiently by finding the attribute in the list of multiple argument options and assigning that to a variable.

Comment: your options are not a mutually exclusive group, what if both `-s` and `-k` was specified?

Comment: it seems like the arguments for `-s` or `-k` are treated the same way, wouldn't it make more sense to just make the s/k be a flag and the arguments handled separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the parser with various inputs, and look at the results:

```
In [108]: def args_options(argv=None):
     ...:     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     ...:     parser.add_argument('-s', help='-s argument help', nargs=3)
     ...:     parser.add_argument('-k', help='-k argument help', nargs=3)
     ...:     arguments = parser.parse_args(argv)
     ...:     return arguments
     ...:
```

With no arguments - both `args.k` and `args.s` are `None`.

```
In [109]: args_options([])
Out[109]: Namespace(k=None, s=None)
```

With `-s` and the right number of arguments, `args.s` is a list of 3 strings.

```
In [110]: args_options(['-s','1','2','3'])
Out[110]: Namespace(k=None, s=['1', '2', '3'])
```

`-k` without arguments - error

```
In [111]: args_options(['-s','1','2','3', '-k'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-s S S S] [-k K K K]
ipython3: error: argument -k: expected 3 arguments
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2



In [112]: args_options(['-s','1','2','3', '-k','4','5','6'])
Out[112]: Namespace(k=['4', '5', '6'], s=['1', '2', '3'])
```

k and s - both as 3 element lists

An example of tests we can do:

```
In [113]: args=args_options(['-k','1','2','3'])
In [114]: args.s is None
Out[114]: True
In [115]: args.k is None
Out[115]: False
In [116]: a,b,c = args.k   # unpack to variables
In [117]: a
Out[117]: '1'
In [118]: b
Out[118]: '2'
In [119]: c
Out[119]: '3'
```

Indexed access of list also works: `args.k[2]`

`vars(args)` creates a dictionary from the `args` object, but I don't think that makes access any easier.

The big message - print `args` to see what your parser produces.  Do this again and again until you understand what it is doing and why.

You could give `-k` a `default=[]`, in produce

```
In [123]: args=args_options(['-s','1','2','3'])
In [124]: args
Out[124]: Namespace(k=[], s=['1', '2', '3'])
```

You could define a `dest` for both, and end up with the values in the args attribute;

```
parser.add_argument('-k', '--ko', dest='something', default=[], nargs=3)
```